# Calling Scala from Node JS routes

Tags: node.js, scala, swagger

Let me describe what I want to achieve.

I have a legacy Scala code which has the backend functionality already implemented. It's running inside a container (say the container name is: my_container). It has the Scala routes etc. everything implemented.

Now I want to write a JavaScript wrapper over it in my Node JS Backend which will invoke the Scala operations. The whole API swagger I am planning to write in Node JS. So basically I will doing like this (rough sketch pseudo code):

Backend.scala:

```
Object Scalabackend {
  def getAPI() : Array<Data> = { ... }
  def postAPI() : Status = {...}
}
```

Route_nodeJS.js

```js
  route({
       method: 'GET',
       url: MyURL
       handler: {
           let result = Scalabackend  .getAPI(..);
           respond.send(result.data) 
       }

  })
```

I would like to get an idea of if there is a framework or something I can use to acheieve this? Or any idea about how natively I may achieve this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why would you put an extra layer of possible failures/complexity with the nodejs? Why not just call the scalabackend directly instead of NodeJS? But I think for nodeJS there's a library simplifying API's called Express or something like that to call endpoints. Just seems unnecessary complex..

Comment: The thing is: we need to write quite a few complex, customized swagger (API doc) for each APIs. Those customizations are written in Node JS already. We want to reuse/leverage those on the top of Scala APIs also. So this extra layer. 
Only the swagger specification we want to be in Node JS. The rest, let it be in Scala.

Comment: Pretty sure you can add those in Scala swell. If you're using the Play framework. I wouldn't be surprised if it's just a flag to turn on. Just seems like you're setting up yourself for pain. For example if you change the scala backend but not the swagger..they won't be accurate. But yeah, I think Express works pretty well for what you looking to do with nodeJS. Imo doing it in scala sounds better :D

Comment: Can you please point me some documentation which I can consider for doing swagger nicely in Scala-2.x? I would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Play? Because they have some stuff about it here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ModuleDirectory , otherewise there seems to be multiple open source projects where people use it. Depending on what dependencies you have , I would consider the options. For example Akka probably has some ok alternatives.

Comment: You're correct. We use Akka with Scala 2.16.x. 
We also want to add a new custom tag like "x-my-custom-tag" in the swagger.

Comment: I just glanced at the documentation, but seems you can add tags without problem. So yeah, either you can check out their examples and it really doesn't fit for you or your team really wants to use an extra layer of a nodeJS endpoint that just calls another endpoint you can probably use Express.

Comment: One thing I am thinking. How is that? Let me explain:
Will write a Node JS route (route.js) that will use some middleware like Express/Fastify which will have all the swagger annotations. And will configure the middleware with some proxy like say fastify-http-proxy having upstream as the scala-route-url, whereas the NodeJS route will be "nodejs-external-route". That way every call will proxy to the backend without having any failure to consider in the NodeJS layer.

Comment: I've no idea. If it seems like a good idea, then go for. it! But usually you wanna avoid multiple points of failure. Hope it works out! :)

Comment: Thanks. I am now playing with a PoC.